# videoview don't support mpg format?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am trying to open a video in a videoView using an url.

Here are the code i use:

```
public void playVideo(){
String path= "http://s3.amazonaws.com/yendis_development/uploads/container/content/4fd79353c83b7260e6000003/3.mpg";
String path1="http://commonsware.com/misc/test2.3gp";

Uri uri=Uri.parse(path);
VideoView video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_view);
video.setVideoURI(uri);
video.start();
}
```

When i use "path1", my VideoView get the video and play it fine. but when i use "path", i don't get the video and i got a dialog saying "Sorry, this video cannot be played".

Why the video worked for the path1(3gp file) and not for path(mpg file) ? You can open path and path1 in the navigator so you can see videos' test, those two link worked in the navigator but not on videoView.

When path, In my logcat, i got this message (error):

```
08-11 17:08:47.411: E/MediaPlayer(10064): error (1, -2147483648)
08-11 17:08:47.411: E/MediaPlayer(10064): Error (1,-2147483648)
08-11 17:08:47.411: D/VideoView(10064): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

Answer (score 0):

mpeg can be compressing the video over a range of different formats/algorithms/codecs and some are supported some are not.
3gp is just one and it is supported (although a very poor format).

Try encoding a video yourself that you'll see all different options.
Usually mp4 on H264 works flawlessly on mobiles.